# Hive Full outer join on 3 tables is working weird

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

3 tables I have created:

Schema:

```
Address(id,address)
Customer(id,customerName)
Account(id,accountNo)

Address('1234569','addrs1')
Address('1111111','addrs2')

Customer('1234569', 'custName')

Account('1234569','accountNo')
```

Query:

```
    select * from (
    (select * from address) as address_temp
      full outer join
    (select * from customer) as customer_temp
      full outer join
    (select * from account) as account_temp
      
    ON
    address_temp.id=customer_temp.id
    AND
    address_temp.id=account_temp.id
    )
```

**Expected Result:**

```
address_temp.id address_temp.address    customer_temp.id    customer_temp.customerName  account_temp.id account_temp.accountNo
                    
1234569 addrs1  1234569 custName    1234569 accountNo
1111111 addrs2  null    null    null    null
```

**Actual Result:**

```
address_temp.id address_temp.address    customer_temp.id    customer_temp.customerName account_temp.id account_temp.accountNo
                    
1234569 addrs1  1234569 custName    1234569 accountNo
1111111 addrs2  1234569 custName    null    null
```

customer details in second row with id 123456is getting linked with account id of 1111111

Don't know how hive is behaving for outer join of three tables, can someone help me here.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want this :

```sql
-- sample data
with Address as (
  select '1234569' id,'addrs1' addr union all
  select '1111111','addrs2'
),
Customer AS (
  select '1234569' id,'custName' addr
),
Account AS (
  select '1234569' id,'accountNo' accountNo
)
-- query starts here
select * from (
  select * from address
) as address_temp 
full outer join (
  select * from customer
) as customer_temp on address_temp.id = customer_temp.id
full outer join (
  select * from account
) as account_temp on address_temp.id = account_temp.id;
```

**Query results**

[image]